# Do the take() and takeUntil() RxJS cause a memory leak?

Tags: rxjs

From the RxJS [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeUntil#example) I see the following example:

```js
const source = interval(1000);
const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const result = source.pipe(takeUntil(clicks));
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

This is close to a code pattern needed for my app but I see a problem.  The `takeUntil` operator subscribes, but as I understand it an `Observer` has no way to unsubscribe from the source `Observable`.  It has no access to a `Subscription` object on which it can call `unsubscribe()`.

So if I understand this correctly then once the user clicks the `source` observable will continue to emit ticks forever to the `takeUntil` which will consume them and do nothing with them.

Am I reading this correctly?  If so is there a generally accepted way to kill the `source` observable from within the `Observer` pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens with `takeUntil` is the following.

When the Observable passed to `takeUntil` as parameter notifies a value, the `subscriber` of the Observable **returned** by `takeUntil` `complete`s and, as a consequence, all the subscriptions created in the `pipe` chain are unsubscribed one after the other in reverse order.

In simpler words, the unsubscription is performed behind the scene by the RxJs internal mechanisms.

To prove this behavior you can try this code

```
const source = interval(1000).pipe(
  tap({ next: (val) => console.log('source value', val) })
);
const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const result = source.pipe(takeUntil(clicks));
result.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

If you run it, you see that the message *'source value', val* is printed until the `click` occurs. After this, no more message is printed on the console, which means that the Observable upstream, i.e. the Observable created by the `interval` function does not notify any more.

You can try the above code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-e6z6ya?file=index.ts).

**SOME DETAILS ON THE INTERNALS**

We can take a look at the internals of the RxJs implementation to see how this *unsubscribe behind the scenes* works.

Let's start from `takeUntil`. In its implementation we see a line like this

```
innerFrom(notifier).subscribe(new OperatorSubscriber(subscriber, () => subscriber.complete(), noop));
```

which, in essence, says that as soon as the `notifier` (i.e. the Observable passed to `takeUntil` as parameter) notifies, the `complete` method is called on the `subscriber`.

The invocation of the `complete` method triggers many things, but eventually it ends up calling the method `execTeardown` of `Subscription` which ends up invoking `unsubscribe` of `OperatorSubscriber` which itself calls `unsubscribe` of `Subscription`.

As we see, the chain is pretty long and complex to follow, but the core message is that the *tearDown* logic (i.e. the logic which is invoked when an Observable completes, errors or is unsubscribed) calls the *unsubscription* logic.

Maybe it is useful to look at one more thing, an implementation of a custom operator directly [from the RxJs documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#creating-new-operators-from-scratch).

In this case, at the end of the definition of the operator, we find this piece of code

```
  // Return the teardown logic. This will be invoked when
  // the result errors, completes, or is unsubscribed.
  return () => {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    // Clean up our timers.
    for (const timerID of allTimerIDs) {
      clearTimeout(timerID);
    }
  };
```

This is the teardown logic for this custom operator and such logic invokes the `unsubscribe` as well as any other cleanup activity.

Comment: I looked at the source code for [takeUntil](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/takeUntil.ts) and I don't see how it manages to deactivate its upstream observable.   Is there some call available to an operator function that does this?

Comment: I have added some more details on the internals of RxJs implementation of `takeUntil` (and other operators) to try to explain how the operator actually calls the unsubscription logic behind the scene

Comment: Thanks for the informative update.  The key insight that I get is that since an operator (which can be fit into a pipe) does its own subscribing it has access to the `Subscription` object (the return value of `subscribe()`).  A regular `Observer` object does not.  That answers my original question.  I hope this helps other people as much as it did for me.